# Trying to make it so that i need a password to remove programs (Windows Server 2019)

Tags: windows-server, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

I'm new to windows servers and I'm in a situation where I have a couple programs that i don't want the client to be able to uninstall without contacting me first. Me and the client are family and i know they can try to do things themselves and mess everything up.

I need a program or a solution to my problem.

I need to make it so that if someone tries to remove a program, it will require a predefined password. I am aware that with a user account you can do this with group policy but i need to do it with my admin account as well.

Any ideas?

I've searched what feels like all of google trying to figure this out but i feel as if someone experienced in windows server might have a simple solution.

Comment: I assume they are admin. There are many ways to remove software beyond running the uninstaller. If the applications drops some files, reg keys and creates a service, maybe it's installed with a MSI: Then you could prevent the MSI being run to uninstall it, but an admin can always delete the service, keys and files. Security software typically has a tamper protection component to prevent an admin doing such things but it typically requires a driver and specific knowlege of the software but even then as an admin you can get around it. So are you after more accidental removal than malicious?

Comment: If you find the software under Programs and Features, then under the registry key: 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` or if 32 on 64: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` for the specific software entry you can create a DWORD value called SystemComponent and set it to 1.  This will hide it from Programs and Features for example.

Comment: I think that registry method would work but mine is defaulted to 1 and they still show. Did you mean 0 by chance?

Comment: Are you looking in the list of applications presented after running: "appwiz.cpl" as setting/creating the value SystemComponent with a DWORD set to 1 should hide the item.  Another basic option would be to create a small little exe, that you put at the start of the UninstallString which prompts for a password, if correct ir runs the rest of the value in the string, i.e. the msiexec command or whatever the uninstall string is.  Again it's all so trivial to bypass is it worth it?

Comment: Thank you for all the comments regarding the matter. I agree that the client shouldn't have access to the admin account and I do agree with the admin account they can bypass various forms of blockers to prevent them from removing the software. However the client isnt that experienced they just think they are. Just to make some of you feel better this isn't some large ORG it's just some server my family member needs for his small business and it is optional. I've decided to just hide the apps as they most likely won't be able to figure out how they are hidden. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to do it with my admin account as well.

It's not possible to put restrictions on what an administrator account can do. An admin account can do *anything* to the Windows OS, which includes removing the restrictions you might put in place.

The correct (and only!) way to restrict what a user can do is to give them a standard user account. Standard users cannot uninstall programs that are installed for all users of the computer.

Comment: Well to be clear. I'm trying to replicate what my antivirus does. I set a password and i cant uninstall it without the password i set. I just wish there was a way to do that for other programs.

Comment: So, even in that case an administrator can bypass such restrictions, even if it is a pain to do so. But implementing even this sort of restriction is non-trivial.

Comment: The reason a password is required to remove antivirus is due to the fact the software itself is removing itself.  If you were to remove it with a hammer like the antivirus cleaner tools most AV companies provide it would not.  This also also assumes you don’t know the password to remove the program or are not an Administrator who can simply change it. Windows doesn’t have a mechanism to require a password to remove software outside of the UAC which only requires an Administrator username and password.  Which is definitely easy to defeat by knowing that information

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're looking for you already know, even if you don't like it: **create *User* accounts for the "client" to use**.

If you don't trust the client with the power of an *Admin* account, don't give them one.

In a comment to another answer you provided more insight into what you envisioned:

> Well to be clear. I'm trying to replicate what my antivirus does. I set a password and i cant uninstall it without the password i set. I just wish there was a way to do that for other programs.

Windows does not provide that functionality. That is why the antivirus program has to provide that level of control itself. If Windows had such a control, the antivirus would simply use what was available and save many man-hours of programming.

As long as the client has access to the Admin account they can do anything they wish to the system. Except repair the damage they cause, of course.

The only other thing you can attempt is to remove the installer/uninstaller for the program in question. Either delete it completely, or move it to somewhere not as obvious as its original directory.

In any case, anything you do, and everything you try, will only slow them down, not stop them, as long as they have the password for the Admin account.

As an extra note, nobody should be "using" any computer from the Admin account. Not even you on your own computer. When *using* the computer, you should be in a *User* account. When doing *administration* to the computer is the time to be in the *Admin* account. And, if there is not a *different* password on the Admin account, the UAC is nothing more than wasted time (and one extra click), offering no more protection than using the computer from the Admin account anyway.